# How to create a column of reverse number matched with other column in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function or loop in R for this specific situation. Below is part of the data set I have in hand:

```
sample  stand   tree    disk
3750 25 23  6
3751 25 23  6
3752 25 23  6
3753 25 23  6
3754 25 23  6
3755 25 23  7
3756 25 23  7
3757 25 23  7
```

My desire output I want is to add the extra column (rev):

```
sample  stand tree  disk rev
3750 25 23  6  5
3751 25 23  6  4
3752 25 23  6  3
3753 25 23  6  2
3754 25 23  6  1
3755 25 23  7  3
3756 25 23  7  2
3757 25 23  7  1
```

I will be appreciated if some one could guide me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using the "data.table" package for this. You can use the `.N` function:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, rev := .N:1, by = .(disk)][]
#    sample stand tree disk rev
# 1:   3750    25   23    6   5
# 2:   3751    25   23    6   4
# 3:   3752    25   23    6   3
# 4:   3753    25   23    6   2
# 5:   3754    25   23    6   1
# 6:   3755    25   23    7   3
# 7:   3756    25   23    7   2
# 8:   3757    25   23    7   1
```

Here, I've assumed you just want to group by "disk", but you can group by multiple columns too.

Comment: Your suggestion did not work. In my data set I have around 2800 sample which each group of disk have different number and are not equal.if you see in my desire output, for group 6 which repeats 5 times I want the reverse of 5 to 1 and so on.

Comment: @user4665665, this approach does not depend on the numbers in each group being equal. My answer matches your desired output. If you can come up with a better sample of the input and output that illustrates the problem you are facing with your actual dataset, you are more likely to get a more relevant answer.

Comment: Assuming you do not have numbers in column "rev". Based on the numbers repeated in column "desk", I want to create the reverse order according to the amount of the numbers in column "desk". for example, 6 repeats 5 times in column "desk", then what I want corresponding to column "rev" is 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 respectively.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the data set where this doesn't work as intended (by editing your original post)? It'd be easier that way.